# Regex does not match if point at the end

Tags: c#, regex

i can't figure out why `[a-zA-Zàáèéìíòóùú'ÀÁÈÉÌÍÒÓÙÚ\s]+$` doesn't match any word(s) ending with a dot, for example:

- Matches `ABC S.R.L`
- Doesn't match `ABC S.R.L.`

I wish I can find a regex that works with bot the strings above, thank you

Comment: Because `$` asserts position at the end of the line and you don't allow it to match `.`

Comment: That's because it explicitly matches only any string that ends with a character in the character set you specified, which does not include dot.

Comment: Use [`[\p{L}\s.]+$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cs.%5d%2b%24&i=ABC+S.R.L%0d%0aABC+S.R.L.&o=m) instead?

Comment: Maybe you're getting confused on `ABC S.R.L` "matching".  It's only matching the the L (everything after the last dot), not the full string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the dot to the list of matching characters:

```
[a-zA-Zàáèéìíòóùú'ÀÁÈÉÌÍÒÓÙÚ\s.]+$
```